# javascript namespacing and pattern for OOP

Tags: javascript

I want to try object oriented js, and I want to know which approach is better out of the two I am trying and why it is better please explain, If there are any other better approach please suggest me.

```
// Approch 1
var thisPage;
abc.forgotPassword = {
    init: function() {
        'use strict';
        thisPage.forgotPasswordFunctionality();
    },
    forgotPasswordFunctionality: function() {
        //some code
    }
};
$(function() {
    thisPage = abc.forgotPassword;
    thisPage.init();
});


// Approch 2
abc.forgotPassword = {
    init: function() {
        'use strict';
        abc.forgotPassword.forgotPasswordFunctionality();
    },
    forgotPasswordFunctionality: function() {
        //some code
    }
};
$(function() {
    abc.forgotPassword.init();
});
```

Comment: The second one because it doesn't depend on an assignment outside the function (i.e. `thisPage = abc.forgotPassword;`).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really object-oriented Javascript- you're just storing functions in an object.

If you want to make it more object-oriented, do something like this:

```
abc.ForgotPasswordHelper = function() {
    this.init = function() { ... }
    this.forgotPasswordFunctionality = function() { ... }
}

var helper = new abc.ForgotPasswordHelper();
helper.init();
```